# Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl - chapter 9 - Ruby 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following the Michael Hartl tutorial and I got stuck in chapter 9.

I need this function to work:

def signed_in?
    !current_user
  end

but this function always return false
even when I'm logged.
I'm sorry for this simple question,
but I'm a begginer and also spend a long
time trying figure it out.
I'm using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.8

thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the code should read

```
def signed_in?
  current_user
end
```

Putting a `!` in front of the call to `current_user` can be read as "return true if it is NOT the current_user".

Your code inside of `SessionsHelper` has a typo. The `:remember_token` cookie is not getting saved off in the `sign_in` method. It should read:

```
def sign_in(user)
  user.remember_me!
  cookies[:remember_token] = { :value => user.remember_token,
                               :expires => 20.years.from_now.utc }
  self.current_user = user
end
```

Not `:remember_toker`.

Comment: Hi, I tried with !current_user, also with !!current_user and withou any !. Nothing worked. I still can't see if I'm logged or not.

Comment: I wrote wrong here, I actually write exactly the same as in the tutorial. I tested in this way: !current_user.nil?, but it is not working.

Comment: Edit your question and post the code to `current_user` as well as where you are calling `signed_in?`. Something is likely wrong there.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I pushed my source to github at https://github.com/heber28/sample_app, please, checkout the file sample_app/app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb and sample_app/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb. My question is, why current_user is always nil if in the session helper it put a value into it.

Comment: You're welcome. You should accept the answer as it will help your approval rating.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a .nil? to current_user like this:

```
def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and decided to work backwards.

1) `def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end`. So I looked for the declaration & definition of current_user associated with a sign-in

2) Here: `def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
    self.current_user = user
  end`. For me, token was misspelled and that fixed it.